# How to adjust HSL values on specific areas of photo using adjustment brush in Lightroom and Camera Raw?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, color, adobe-camera-raw, layers

How to adjust **HSL values** on specific areas of photo using **adjustment brush in Lightroom and Camera Raw.** 
We can see slider control for temp, tint, exposure... But couldn't control the HSL values.

Also, Is there a **Adjustment layer** to control Luminance like we have for Curves, Levels, saturation... in Photoshop?

Any Alternative methods or Tips will be Helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only values that can be brushed are the ones shown in the brush.
I would guess that Adobe feels the others are out of the scope of lightroom, which is "only" a image editing tool, not an image creating tool like photoshop.
So maybe you'd need photoshop and use the RAW file from there.

Comment: @vishnu camera raw tends to do the same things that LR does. I wouldn't be surprised if they are the same thing internally. After all, LR is just some file management software wrapped around a raw processor.

Answer (score 2):

Although quite laborious, one way to get to where you want to go would be to edit the raw file globally in Lightroom and export a separate version of the entire photo edited specifically for each of the areas you wish to develop differently. Then combine them using masking and layering in photoshop.